# Pythonで__instancecheck__メソッドが呼び出されない

Tags: python

Pythonで__instancecheck__メソッドが呼び出されない場合があります。
以下のコードを実行すると

Falseになるはず→ True
Falseになるはず→ False
Falseになるはず→ False
Falseになるはず→ False

と表示されます。
本当は一つ目がFalseと表示されるべきですがTrueと出てしまいます。
なぜ呼び出されないのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

```
class Analysis(type):
    def __instancecheck__(self, other):
        return False

class SMA(metaclass = Analysis):
    pass

sma=SMA()
print('Falseになるはず→',isinstance(sma, SMA))
print('Falseになるはず→',isinstance(1, SMA))
print('Falseになるはず→',isinstance([], SMA))
print('Falseになるはず→',isinstance('', SMA))
```

Comment: [Why \_\_instancecheck\_\_ is not always called depending on argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731207/why-instancecheck-is-not-always-called-depending-on-argument)

Comment: 英語が苦手でよくわからないです。
呼び出されない原因は仕様なのでしょうか。
自分のコードに問題があったと思っていたのですが、
そんなことはなかったのでしょうか。

Comment: ソースコード上ではまず最初に type check を行って、 オブジェクトが指定されたクラスのインスタンスであれば即座に True を返しますので `__instancecheck__` は実行されません。ここでは sma が SMA クラスのインスタンスなので True が返って終了となります。

Comment: argusさんありがとうございました。
この現象は仕様のようです。
__instancecheck__を使わずに関数を自分で定義して書くことにします。
回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: @argus さん、よろしければそれを回答として投稿していただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

[argusさんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19624/python%E3%81%A7-instancecheck-%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B3%E5%87%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#comment18284_19624)より転載。

> ソースコード上ではまず最初に type check を行って、 オブジェクトが指定されたクラスのインスタンスであれば即座に True を返しますので `__instancecheck__` は実行されません。ここでは sma が SMA クラスのインスタンスなので True が返って終了となります。